# nginx reverse proxy on docker - setup custom ip for each domain

Tags: nginx, docker

I have nginx proxy reverse on docker. On the host server I have service failover ip.
I want to set each domain on nginx custom IP, because at the moment all domains are using the main IP of my server.

How can I do that?

Can someone please help with the same. Below is my code

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [nginx documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen), you add the IP address to the `listen` directive:

```
listen 127.0.0.1:443 ssl http2;
```

tells nginx to bind that virtual host to the localhost IP address port 443. If that hostname is reached via some other IP address, then nginx will route the request to the default virtual host.

Comment: I using proxy reverse on docker.
My default.conf for domains look like:
location / {
  proxy_pass http://domain.domain.us;
  auth_basic "Restricted Content";
     auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.m-htpasswd;
 }

I should add in location / {...}   set_real_ip_from ip.ip.ip/32; ?

Comment: Is this a new question? If yes, please open it as a new question. If it is additional information for this question, please edit the question and add information there.